# most elegant way to return a string from List<int>

Tags: c#

What is the most elegant way to return a string from a List
ok, yeah, I know I can do something like

```
public string Convert(List<int> something)
{
    var s = new StringBuilder();
    foreach(int i in something)
        s.AppendFormat("{0} ", i);

    return s.ToString();
}
```

but i m sure there is a way to do this with lambdas
I tried also to append to a stringbuilder but that is not doing whats expected

Comment: Didn't Eisntein say something about elegance once?  Can't remember what it was for the life of me!

Comment: "If you are out to describe the truth, leave elegance to the tailor."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

IMO, you were better off with your original version; LINQ is great, but it isn't the answer to every problem. In particular, the `string.Join` approach demands an extra array (for little gain), and the `Aggregate` approach uses **lots** of intermediate strings.

Perhaps make it an extension method, though - and lose the `Format` stuff:

```
public static string Concatenate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, string delimiter)
{
   var s= new StringBuilder();
   bool first = true;
   foreach(T t in source) {
      if(first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        s.Append(delimiter);
      }
      s.Append(t);
   }    
   return s.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It's funny; if .NET provided a built-in function called, say, ListToString, and someone posted the answer, "Just use ListToString," everyone would call it elegant. But if someone wrote a function that did the exact same thing internally, just by seeing the code people would call it clunky. LINQ may look quite concise, but that doesn't mean there's not plenty going on under the covers.

Comment: @Dan - well put. Indeed, much of LINQ is *about* hiding complexity - the complexity is still there, of course ;-p.

Comment: what do you mean by the "aggregate" approach, the LINQ?

Comment: People would call it clunky because these kinds of low-level tricks ARE clunky. It's why we have LINQ etc. If we wanted to deal with decisions like these all the time instead of only very rarely in special circuimstances we'd probably be working ina language that didn't run as bytecode on a VM. In 99 % of all applications, using the LINQ method is more readable, maintainable and heck, a lot of the time it's probably even faster than what you'd write yourself too.

Answer (score 21):

```
String result = String.Join(" ", list.Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray());
```

If it's just a collection of type `List<int>` (and not `List<int?>`) there could only be 0's instead of NULLs.

But to address the hypothetical or more general `null` problem one could add a `Where(item => item != null)`, use the conditional operator, or the null coalescing operator. But every "fix" added to the expression will make it less readable and elegant.

Comment: Sorry, how is this elegant?  Just because it's new and Linq'y doesn't mean it's automatically elegant.  By the way I have enjoyed using Linq, just not for everything.

Comment: That can be important. Aggregate + stringbuilder would probably be better.

Comment: It's a kind of elegant because it's simple and compact. It's obviously not the best or most performant solution. And I completly missed the null problem.

Comment: Its also "elegant" simply because it uses the existing String.Join(). That fact instantly communicates a lot to future readers which the roll-your-own-loop approach would not.

Answer (score 12):

Use string.Join:

```
string.Join(" ", something.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToArray())
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `string.Join`:

```
List<int> data = ..;
var result = string.Join(";", data); // (.NET 4.0 only)
var result = string.Join(";", data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); // (.NET 3.5)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static string Join(this List<int> list) {
        return string.Join(" ", list.Select(item => item.ToString()).ToArray());
    }
}
```

usage:

```
string s = new List<int> {1, 2, 3}.Join();
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking advantage of both StringBuilder and LINQ:

```
    public static string SpaceOut(this IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        if (list.Count()==)) return string.Empty;

        var res = new StringBuilder();

        list.Take(list.Count() - 1).ToList().ForEach(i => res.Append(i.ToString() + " "));
        res.Append(list.Last().ToString());

        return res.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string result = list.Aggregate("", (str, i) => str + " " + i).TrimStart(' ');
```

Comment: You need to convert `i` to a string in the lambda.

Comment: You actually don't; it's implied by C#.

Answer (score 0):

Use LINQ and accumulate:

```
string res = list.Select(x => x.ToString()).Aggregate("", (a,b) => a + " " + b);
```

and saves an intermediate array (but for a large list creates O(n) garbage strings).

Answer (score 0):

Impelemnt an enumerable extension like this:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions{
   public static string JoinStrings<TItem>(this IEnumerable<TItem> sequence, string separator)
   {
      return sequence.JoinStrings(separator, (TItem item) => item.ToString());
   }
}
```

And then use it like this on an IEnumerables :

```
var myList = new List<int>() {1,2,3,4};
var myString = myList.JoinStrings(", ");
```