# Convert List<int> to delimited string list

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [most elegant way to return a string from List<int>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334072/most-elegant-way-to-return-a-string-from-listint)

I'm not sure the easiest way to do this.  I simply want to add a ; between each value and spit it out as one string.  I don't see that you can do this with ToString().  I'd have to loop through and create a stringbuilder and append & add a ";".

Comment: sorry that is an List<int> not List<string>

Comment: I need to convert a List<string> to a delmited string.  So "123;343;222"

Comment: @coffeeaddict: It's OK to edit your original question. That's better than hoping people will read all the details in the comments.

Comment: I think this is probably an exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334072/most-elegant-way-to-return-a-string-from-listint

Comment: Except that there is now a better (.NET 4.0 only) answer.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

**UPDATED** to use `List<int>` instead of `List<string>`

Use `string.Join`:

```
List<int> data = ..;
var result = string.Join(";", data); // (.NET 4.0+)
var result = string.Join(";", data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()); // (.NET 3.5)
```

Comment: sorry I have changed the question, my mistake

Comment: I've updated the answer to match.

Comment: +1 for .Net 4 enumerable string.Join

Comment: interesting.  I had also tried myIntList.ToString().ToArray() but must be doing something wrong

Comment: var result = data.ConvertAll(c=>c.ToString());

where data is List<int>

Answer (score 8):

```
string.Join(";", myList.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 4):

Just use the join

```
string combinedString = String.Join(";", arrayName);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
List<String> list = new List<String>() { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E" };
String joindString1 = String.Join(";", list.ToArray());
String joindString2 = list.Aggregate((s1, s2) => s1 + ";" + s2);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Enumerable.Aggregate which can give extra flexibility.

```
var data = new List<int> { 1,2,3 };
var sb = new StringBuilder(100);

// do some other stuff with sb

sb = data.Aggregate(sb, (b, d) => b.Append(d).Append(';'));
if( data.Count > 0 ) sb.Length--;

//do some more stuff with sb

var str = sb.ToString();
```