# Convert vector<int> to delimited string

Tags: c++, string, vector

As I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135397/convert-listint-to-delimited-string-list) there is a fast and short way to Convert vector to string separated with a character in c#:

```
var result = string.Join(";", data); 
var result = string.Join(";", data.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
```

I wan to know is there a same way in c++ to do this?

Comment: No, there isn't with `std::string`, if you meant that!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> data = {42, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ";"));

    std::string result( oss.str() );
    std::cout << result << "\n";
}
```

N.B. In C++11, you can use the more general form

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::copy(begin(data), end(data), std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ";"));
```

Where the using-declarations are not required if ADL can be used (like in the example above).

---

Also possible, but maybe a bit less efficient:

```
std::string s;
for(auto const& e : v) s += std::to_string(e) + ";";
```

which can be written via `std::accumulate` in `<algorithm>` as:

```
std::string s = std::accumulate(begin(v), end(v), std::string{},
    [](std::string r, int p){ return std::move(r) + std::to_string(p) + ";"; });
```

(IIRC there was some method to eliminate the copying, maybe by taking the lambda-parameter by reference `std::string& r`.)

---

A version w/o the trailing semi-colon (thanks to [Dietmar Kühl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1120273/dietmar-kuhl)):

```
std::vector<int> data = {42, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

std::ostringstream out;
if (!v.empty())
{
    std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, ";"));
    out << v.back();
}

std::string result( out.str() );
std::cout << result << "\n";
```

Comment: @Robᵩ I missed the `#include <string>` ;)

Comment: +1 It might help the pedagogy if you named your input and result variables similarly to OP's: `std::vector<int> data` and `std::string result`.

Comment: Sadly, there is trailing semicolon where there probably shouldn't be one.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, but I couldn't come up with a similarly simple solution to get rid of it.

Comment: I was thinking something like `std::string s = v.empty()? std::string{""}: std::accumulate(v.begin() + 1, v.end(), v.front(), [](std::string const& s, int i) { return s + ";" + std::to_string(i); });`

Comment: @DietmarKühl That's quite nice. There's some additional copying like in my `accumulate` example (from the intermediary result to the `s + ";"`). Maybe, as I mentioned, taking by ref + moving could help.

Comment: ... or, of course, `std::ostringstream out; if (!v.empty()) { std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, ";")); out << v.back(); }; std::string s = out.str();`

Comment: @DietmarKühl Should `to_string` be called unqualified?

Comment: @thirdDeveloper Use `v.begin()` and `v.end()`. I tend to use C++11's free functions `begin` and `end` via ADL; it's one character less to type ;)

Comment: @DyP: seem it wouldn't have any reason to find `std::to_string()` when called with an `int`. You'd need `using std::to_lower;` before it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl Yes, was meant as a more general question (similar to `std::begin` and `std::swap`).

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on the accepted answer a little, I took the code and made a generic template version that works not only with a vector of ints but works with any types that work with stringstream:

```
template <typename T>
std::string VectorToCSV(const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    if (!vec.empty())
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec) - 1, std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, ";"));
        out << vec.back();
    }

    return out.str();
}
```

This works with Template Argument Deduction, so to call it like this:

```
// Vector of ints example
std::vector<int> vec_of_ints = { 1, 2, 3, 4};    
std::string ints_csv = VectorToCSV(vec_of_ints);

// Vector of strings example
std::vector<std::string> vec_of_strings = { "Hello", "World"};
std::string strings_csv = VectorToCSV(vec_of_strings);
```